# (Unreal) VS 2019 cannot find GameFramework folder, and many other errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

So I just started learning unreal with c++. I've been following youtube tutorials and many of them tell me to make a c++ class that inherits from character.h. For the youtubers, this creates and opens up some skeleton code in VS 2019 with no errors, and also IDE features such as autocomplete.

However, when I do the same thing, there is no autocomplete nor error underlining for about 20 minutes, after which I get an error trying to find "GameFramework/Character.h" in the include, and red underlines all over the place, even under tokens such as "class".

I made sure to check c++ development and unreal when I installed VS 2019. I also tried VS 2017 but that just doesn't give me any errors at all, even after typing random stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Intellisense squiggles don't work by default with unreal, they need the live recompile feature enabled. Epic do have a [bit of documentation on this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, solved my problems but it's still takes about 20 minutes of processing time to start highlighting errors, any way to fix this?